# JavaScript(jQuery)における文字列中に変数を記述する方法ってあるでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, jquery

PHPだと、

```
$hoge = "ほげ";
$huga = "ああああああ{$hoge}いいいい";
```

> 結果: ああああああほげいいいい

というような記述が出来ると思いますが、JavaScript(jQuery)で似たような記述方法ってあるでしょうか？
検索したのですが、見つけられなかったため質問です。

Comment: ECMAScript 6 で導入された `template literal` を使ってみてはどうですか。具体的には \`(バッククォート)で対象文字列を囲みます。`var huga = \`ああああああ${hoge}いいいい\`;`

Comment: ありがとうございます。@unarist さんも同様のことを仰っていますね。近年対応された言語仕様のようなので、しばらくは使用しないでおきたいと思います。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ES2015(ES6) から導入された Template Literals がまさにその機能です。通常文字列リテラルに使われる `''`' `""` の代わりに ``` `` ``` で囲み、その中に `${ }` で囲んだ式を埋め込むことができます。

[Template strings - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

```js
var hoge = "ほげ";
document.write(`ああああああ${hoge}いいいい<br/>`);

var foo = 16;
document.write(`${foo} * 2 = ${foo * 2}`);
```

対応状況としてはInternetExplorerとAndroidBrowser、iOS8以前のSafariで使えないぐらいで、最新のモダンブラウザであれば普通に使うことができます。

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-template_literals

それ以前のブラウザでも動かしたい場合、あるいはHTML出力などでエスケープ処理が必要な場合は、テンプレートエンジンを使うことになるかと思います。jQueryでもそのような機能は持ち合わせていません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
unix系のシェルみたいに` `` `行をコマンド行みたいに認識させるのに似ていますね。最近対応されたということを知りましたので、まだ積極的には使いたくないとおもいます。普通に `var huga="ああああああ"+huga+"いいいい";` という風につなげてやっていこうと思います。

Answer (score 1):

old IEなども対応しなければならない状況なら、underscore.js#template がいいかもしれません.
http://underscorejs.org/#template

```
<script src="underscore.js"></script>
<script>
  (function() {
    var myStr = '!hello world!';
    var myTemplate = _.template('result: <%= variableNameInTemplate1 %>');

    // "result: !hello world!"
    console.log(myTemplate({variableNameInTemplate1: myStr}));
  })();
</script>
```

babelなどのトランスパイラも必要なく、単独で動作するので手軽です.

1行程度の操作なら文字列連結で済ませるのがよいです.
HTML片の出力のような、大きな文字列を生成するなら一考に値すると思います.

Answer (score 1):

sprintf関数がなさそうなので、replaceを利用する方法もよいかもしれません。

```
var $hoge = "ほげ";
var $huga = "ああああああ%hogeいいいい".replace("%hoge", $hoge);
```